# Looking for a SF story about robotic explorers who discover intelligent organic life on a planet

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, humor

I read a humorous science fiction story some ten to twenty years ago about robotic explorers who discover a planet, perhaps Earth, with intelligent organic lifeforms and can't quite believe it. They argue about how impossible that is. Apparently all intelligence in the galaxy is machine-based.

In the end, I think, they decide against contacting the organics. Nor do they tell the rest of the galaxy about their discovery because they won't be believed.

Any clues?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"They're Made Out of Meat" by Terry Bisson, originally published in 1991, and nominated for the 1992 Nebula Award for best short story.

http://www.terrybisson.com/page6/page6.html

Comment: That's it! Thanks for the link, it's a funny story. Not particularly important, but funny.